# Is there a way to list all the Bindings to an Ember.Object?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Example in coffeescript

```
window.APP = Ember.Application.create()

APP.stuff = Ember.Object.create(
  name: "The Name"
)

APP.things = Ember.Object.create(
  nameBinding: "APP.stuff.name"
)

APP.gizmos = Ember.Object.create(
  nameBinding: "APP.stuff.name"
)
```

Is there anyway to detect that APP.stuff has 2 bindings to its name property?

Comment: You can answer your own question, simply wait for a sufficient amount of time. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer after digging through lots of source code....

I'm not sure the Devs recommend this approach....but it gives me what I want.

Basically the answer is to call...

```
Ember.meta(APP.stuff)
```

This returns an object that contains a "watching" hash, which contains the properties being watched and the number of watchers.

Ember is cool.

Comment: yep, but it seems to be a private method: `You generally will not access this information directly but instead work with higher level`. See http://goo.gl/ME87m . But I don't know other way to do that.